Remove unwanted branches from `git branch -a` output
I ran git fetch remote --all, and now when I run git branch -a it spits out a ton of remote branches that I don't care about. How do I selectively remove branches from this output? All the branches on the remotes are active, valid branches. I just don't care about most of them, so I want to remove them from my local system.
For example, I get output similar to"
  remotes/xxx/RELEASE/12.1
  remotes/xxx/RELEASE/12.1.1
  remotes/xxx/RELEASE/12.2
  remotes/xxx/RELEASE/12.3
  remotes/xxx/RELEASE/12.3.1
  remotes/xxx/RELEASE/12.4
  remotes/xxx/RELEASE/12.4.1
  remotes/xxx/master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/RELEASE/12.4.1
  remotes/origin/feat/yarn-upgrade
  remotes/origin/fix/hide-homepage
  remotes/origin/master

In this example, I don't care about any of the 12.1, 12.2, or 12.3 branches from the xxx remote.
How do I remove them from this listing? They can not be deleted from the remote, as they're still valid branches. I've pruned all the stale branches.

"In this example, I don't care about any of the 12.1, 12.2, or 12.3 branches from the xxx remote" Then don't look at them. It's just a list, and it's a correct list of what you asked for. What's the problem? You don't see any of them when you say git branch so it's not an "issue" of any kind.

Are they active and valid? Is the project working on 12.1, 12.1.1, 12.2, 12.3, 12.3.1, 12.4, and 12.4.1 at the same time? I hope they aren't. Maybe they could be replaced by tags.

You can delete the unwanted remote branches with git branch -d --remote <remote branch>, but then they'll just return with your next git fetch.
To maintain your trimmed list, you'll have to be careful to fetch only those branches you're interested in. You can fetch specific branches like git fetch origin <this branch> <that branch>, but a single git fetch will undo your work.
Instead, configure the default for git fetch in .git/config. Let's say you only wanted to fetch master and RELEASE/12.4.1.
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:ruby/ruby.git
        fetch = refs/heads/master
        fetch = refs/heads/RELEASE/12.4.1

Now git fetch will only fetch those two branches.
NOTE: I don't recommend this. Branches in Git are extremely cheap. IMO this is not worth the effort and will only cause more problems. Instead, I recommend setting fetch.prune and fetch.pruneTags to remove remote branches and tags as they are deleted from the remote. Ask the remote to delete old branches, or replace old release branches with tags. I doubt they are working on 12.1, 12.1.1, 12.2, 12.3, 12.3.1, 12.4, and 12.4.1 at the same time.

Thank you Schwern, this was a helpful response. Normally I do specify the branches I want to fetch.
